# SiteFinity - Querystrings in URLs are being duplicated

Tags: telerik, sitefinity

in Sitefinity 3 (yes, using 3 because 4 is so horrible right now) I have content in a content editor. I add a link to the content including the sfref attribute. In my link, I have a querystring

http://mysite/page.aspx?x=123

when I save, SF changes the url and adds another querystring so the result is

http://mysite/page.aspx?x=123?x=123

no matter what I try, this still happens. Ideas, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dustin,

I actually ran into the same problem a couple of days ago and did some Googling. I found this Sitefinity post and it has some code that fixes the issue. It appears to just have been a bug in Sitefinity.

http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-3-x/developing-with-sitefinity/problem-with-querystring-params-being-duplicated-by-generic-content-control.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice. When I posted about it, I got a silly response of, "What are you talking about?"